# Template of Sharepoint Sites in Sharepoint 2013 created by CRM Microsoft Dynamics

Tags: site-template, web-template, dynamics-crm

At work I have got a CRM Microsoft Dynamics. At work we have got a lot of projects. When the new project is created in CRM we want to make a new site or site Colection for only this project. With a rights to this person which works on this project.

This will be a lot of data. How could I store this data with no ingeretion for main Sharepoint ?

How prepere a Solution to Site Template, or Web Page Template to create a site dynamicaly when the Project is created by user in CRM.